# Check BlackBerry OS version 

Tags: javascript, jquery, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

How do I get the BlackBerry OS version via javascript or jquery in a Webworks app?

I tried the following code from a thread "[detect blackberry os version](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=236931)" but it isn't working for me:

```
var limit = '4.5.0.127';
var version = /BlackBerry\w+\/([\d\.]+)/i.exec(navigator.userAgent);
if (version[1] && version[1] < limit) {
    location.href='notcompatible.cfm';
}
```

Comment: Since adopting feature/capability detection sometime early last decade I've forgotten all about userAgent strings. What are they used for again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on this document...

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-detect-the-BlackBerry-Browser/ta-p/559862

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    if (ua.indexOf("BlackBerry") >= 0) {
        if (ua.indexOf("Version/") >= 0) { // ***User Agent in BlackBerry 6 and BlackBerry 7
            Verposition = ua.indexOf("Version/") + 8;
            TotLenght = ua.length;
            document.write("Jorgesys  BB OS Version :: " + ua.substring(Verposition, Verposition + 3));
        }
        else {// ***User Agent in BlackBerry Device Software 4.2 to 5.0
            var SplitUA = ua.split("/");
            document.write("Jorgesys BB OS Version :: " + SplitUA[1].substring(0, 3));
        }
    }
</script>
```

- be sure to have Javascript Enabled! =)

Comment: :((, your code displays nothing on my simulator. any answers pls.

Comment: Yep by using this instructions: Go to Browser->Options->Browser Configuration->Scroll down->Enable "Support JavaScript"->Save Options; and it doesn't work, :(( mommyyy..

Comment: i have tested this script in several devices, OS versions, mmm do you have the link of your .html page?

Comment: it works with my blackberry simulator's browser, but when integrating it with my webworks app, it just destroys everything. any help?

Comment: Finally, It seem like the code above works!, yeah... tnx jorgesys.

Comment: what was your problem Cache issues?

Answer (score 1):

If you have experienced trouble detecting BlackBerry 10 (as I did after reading this answer!), be aware that the user agent string has changed in BB10, as explained in http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/08/blackberry-10-user-agent-string/

In my specific case, I wanted to check if the version was just BB10, for which the next code is enough:

```
isBlackBerry: function() {
    // Only works with the latest version: BlackBerry 10
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/BB10/i);
}
```